# How to sequence row based on another row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, sequence

I am trying to convert a formula from excel to pandas.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
Column A    Column B 
H  
H  
H  
J  
J  
J  
J  
K  
K
```

I want to fill column B to increment while the value in column A remains the same. In the example above, this would be:

```
Column A     Column B
H            1
H            2
H            3
J            1
J            2
J            3
J            4
K            1
K            2
```

In excel, the formula would be `=IF(A2<>A1,1,B1+1)`

How can I apply this formula in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the following vectorised method:

**Code:**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['H', 'H', 'H', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'K', 'K']})
>>> df['B'] = df.groupby((df['A'].shift(1) != df['A']).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
   A  B
0  H  1
1  H  2
2  H  3
3  J  1
4  J  2
5  J  3
6  J  4
7  K  1
8  K  2
```

**Explanation:**

First, we use [`df['A'].shift(1) != df['A']`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to compare column A with column A shifted by 1. This yields:

```
>>> df['A'] != df['A'].shift(1)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Next, we use [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to return the cumulative sum over that column. This gives us:

```
>>> (df['A'] != df['A'].shift(1)).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Now, we can use [`GroupBy.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) as usual to enumerate each item in ascending order, adding 1 to start the index at 1. Note that we can't just use

```
df.groupby('A').cumcount()
```

Because if, for example, we had:

```
>>> df
   A
0  H
1  H
2  H
3  J
4  J
5  J
6  J
7  K
8  K
9  H
```

This would give us:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').cumcount() + 1
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    1
8    2
9    4
dtype: int64
```

Note that the final row is `4` and not `1` as expected.