# How to sequence rows based on another row?

Tags: python, pandas

Pls check this : [How to sequence row based on another row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976809/how-to-sequence-row-based-on-another-row)
input

```
Column A     

H            

H            

H            

J            

J            

J            

J            

K
```

The above thread covers the case where formula is :  `=IF(A2<>A1,1,B1+1)`

How would you go about if the output you require is `=IF(A2=A1,1,B1+1)`

output would look like

```
Column A     Column B
H            1
H            1
H            1
J            2
J            2
J            2
J            2
K            3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift` and `cumsum`:

```
df["new"] = df["Column A"].ne(df["Column A"].shift(1)).cumsum()

print (df)

  Column A  Column B  new
0        H         1    1
1        H         1    1
2        H         1    1
3        J         2    2
4        J         2    2
5        J         2    2
6        J         2    2
7        K         3    3
```